# ntpd requires stripping out the HEX: prefix from SHA1 and SHA256 hex keys to interwork with chrond server

Tags: ntpd, chrony

I am new to this business, and could not find the answers to the following:

- In order for ntpd client to sync up with chronyd server using a hex key value, I found that I need to strip out the HEX: prefix from the hex keys used by chronyd before I upload this key file to my ntpd client. Is this is a known fact about this type of interworking, or a specific issue with my client?
- ntpd requires full key length when using hex keys, i.e., SHA-1 has to be 40-hex symbols, SHA-256 64-hex symbols. Is this design intent of ntpd, and a known practice used by IT when generating and configuring ntpd keys?
- ntpd implementation assumes (even in latest version ntp4.2.8p17) that if strlen(key) <= 20, then it is treated as ASCII characters. If strlen(key) > 20 characters, then it is treated as hex format.

  1. Why 20 is the boundary limit to make this segregation?  Gathering from RFCs, MD5 digest is 128 bits, SHA-1 digest is 160 bits, SHA256 is 256, etc. Was the 20-characters limit based on early implementation of ntpd when MD5 and SHA-1 were only on mind?
  2. Is this 20-character limit known and expected by IT folks in industry, and accepted as a de-facto standard?
  3. What repercussions can you think of if this limit is changed to be based on key type, i.e., if SHA-1 then limit is 20, if SHA-256 then limit is 32,... Could this cause backward compatibility issues?

Comment: How are you getting these keys that are "used by chronyd"?  Are you invoking a command to make chrony/chronyd output them?  Are you reading them from a chronyd configuration file or logfile?

Comment: I am just dumping the keys from the chronyd key file.

Comment: You're not being specific.  Is "dumping" the file a specific `chronyd` command, or are you just invoking `cat /path/to/chronyd/keyfile`?

Comment: Yes used cat to dump the chronyd key file.